# Clang AST: get CXXCtorInitializer list for for constructors that their declaration is not also a definition

Tags: c++, clang, abstract-syntax-tree, matcher

I'm confrunting with the following issue. The inits from CXXConstructorDecl returns an empty list in the following scenario:

```
class Test3 {
  int a = 2;
  int b;
  Test3();
};

Test3::Test3() : b(0) {
}
```

Now if i change the definition of the Test3 constructor and i make it inline as:

```
class Test3 {
  int a = 2;
  int b;
  Test3()
  : a(2)
  , b(2){

  }
};
```

Everything works fine and function inits returns a list of 2 items for a and b.

Comment: Can you show us a minimal complete example?

Comment: Try calling `getBody()` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do it is to do the following:

```
    if (!ctor->isThisDeclarationADefinition()) {
  for (auto ctorFromList : ctor->redecls()) {
    CXXConstructorDecl *ctr = dyn_cast_or_null<CXXConstructorDecl>(
        ctorFromList);

    if (ctr != ctor) {
      ctor = ctr;
      break;
    }
  }
```

Now ctor is a pointer to the definition that also has the list for inits.